# p:commandLink not fires action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

`p:commandLink`s with ids `cl1` and `cl2` do not fire actions. There is nothing on Tomcat console, nothing on Firebug console.

Where should i look for the problem in such situations, i think i am totally desperate without any error or exception, in both consoles.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org/"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:form>
        <ui:repeat var="sharing" value="#{sharingController.myList}">
            <ui:repeat var="sharingComment" value="#{sharing.subCommentList}">
                <p:commandLink id="cl1" value="" process="@this"  action="#{reportController.reportSharingComment(sharingComment)}" style="float:right;" id="sharingComment_alert" styleClass="icon_alert" title="#{msg['label.report']}" update=":messages" >
                </p:commandLink>
                 <p:commandLink value="" id="cl2" process="@this" action="#{sharingController.deleteComment(sharingComment)}" style="float:right;" id="sharingComment_delete" styleClass="icon_delete" title="#{msg['label.delete']}" update="@form :messages">
                </p:commandLink>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

I tried with a concrete list in the nested `ui:repeat` in post construct then commandlinks was fired, but I must iterate over field lists like sub commentlists of every sharing in `myList`. I'm loading both `myList` and for every sharing I load the `subCommentlist` in a for in post construct, but I still cannot make the `commandLink`s fire.

Comment: Can you please only post the relevant code?  There are hundreds of lines of markup within `<ui:remove>` tags that are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Sometimes, SO members tell to share everything to find out the problem, i am going to delete `ui:remove` s

Comment: Are you sure that this component isn't inside another `<h:form>` right? Because that would be `form` nesting, so your `UIInput`s won't work. Also, next time just post the relevant code to reproduce the problem, not your whole code. More info: [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656/1065197)

Comment: This `<ui:composition>` is included in another xhtml page but, there is no other covering `<h:form>`

Comment: Thanks for the link, i am going to try the advises.

Comment: There's too much code noise. I can't imagine that for example the `style="border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;"` is relevant to the problem. Does the problem disappear when you remove it? No? Keep it out then. Edit your question to post a real SSCCE, please. That is, the smallest possible code snippet which we (and you!) should be able to copy'n'paste'n'run unmodified in a completely blank playground project with everything set to default (unless otherwise specified) in order to see the concrete problem ourselves.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza can you look at my question update, thanks in advance

Comment: @BalusC can you look at my question update, thanks in advance

Comment: For anyone else facing the same,
Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

The 4. point solved:
Putting the bean in the view scope and/or making sure that you load the data model in (post)constructor of the bean (and thus not in the getter method!) should fix it.